# vcvarsall.bat not found while installing python Cassandra driver

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-2010, gcc, cassandra

I am trying to install Python Cassandra Driver and constantly getting error "vcvarsall.bat not found"

I tried using lots of solutions posted already in stackoverflow but non of them are working.
here is what i tried-

1. Using mingw gcc compiler.I followed every step, setting the path variable etc.
   and then tried using "setup.py install --compiler=mingw32" but again got same error.
2. i have VS08 installed. and also path variable "VS80COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\Tools\" is set. This is also not working.
3. Installed mingw- base tools,make tool,gcc compiler and then again followed  step one but no help.

-edit
operating system windows enterprise N x64.
python version-2.7

I tried to install it on my windows server machine using first step and it worked fine but not working on my laptop.

Comment: Which python version you're building it for would be useful (also you missed the most important part of the OS description, but that shouldn't matter anyhow). I'm pretty sure you need VS2010 for newer python versions so that's probably a good bet. You may just try and see what happens if you set VS100COMNTOOLS to your VS2008 install.

Comment: python version- python 2.7
and OS -windows x64  enterprise n

OK i will try and see.

Comment: Not working ... I think i need to install VS2010 and try that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://bugs.python.org/issue7511. There is a patch which could help

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue with this too. I had visual studio installed as well.

Finally I found this.

http://ckcollab.com/blog/?p=199#comment-678

All you need to do is run the following from the command line.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\vcvars64.bat"

I hope this helps!

Comment: I resolved this issue already and i also dont remember exactly what i did but thanks for your suggestion.